# MySQL duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql

I get a *duplicate entry* error when inserting a row on a field that is not unique. But this is primary key. What might be the reason?

Comment: I think this question is very valid, just add a little more description and I think people would be more helpful (sorry for your bad experience).

Answer (score 7):

Primary keys are by their very definition, unique. You cannot insert a duplicate value for a primary key.

To elaborate, a primary key combines a unique constraint with "not null" constraint. By that definition, a primary key may not be null and must be unique in the table.